# Do you have any “Family Feud” style questions and answers for a game for high school students?

Tags: technology

I am gathering questions and responses in math, science, and technology for a "Family Feud" style game for high school students. I am having trouble finding and thinking of questions, especially in the technology realm. Technology (programming or general tech) questions are preferred.

If you have never seen the game show, "Family Feud" involves two teams trying to guess the most popular responses to questions asked to a group of 100 respondents. The team must guess all the popular responses to get the points for the question. For example, if the question is, "What are the major tags in HTML 4.0?", the responses might be:

1. P (64 votes)
2. DIV (16 votes)
3. TABLE (8 votes)
4. BLINK (4 votes)

Comment: I'm not sure how you plan to get the "votes" to go with the options, unless you actually plan on asking these questions to 100 technology professionals.

Comment: Welcome to Programmers.  Please read the site's FAQ and guidelines to asking questions.  After you do, please come back and edit this question as it doesn't meet the site's guidelines.  This question is producing list answers which are not constructive.

Comment: @Zeke: I'm just planning on using questions with pretty generic answers (like @mootinator's post below).  Ranking will be informal from my own small team.

Comment: @Walter: Where would be an appropriate place to pose this question?  I was directed here after posting on StackOverflow (trying to make it a Community Wiki), and the FAQ seemed like this was appropriate to ask here.

Comment: Someone should take this concept beyond high school students. It would be a lot of fun. In fact, why can't Stack Overflow itself serve as the survey platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Family Feud questions are always in the form of "name something that ..." not "What are all the ...". so you could have "name a programming language" or "name a data type". You could also have "we asked 100 programmers, what is your monitor resolution" or "name an add-in for Visual Studio" or "name an editor for working with HTML".

The trick isn't coming up with the questions - it's getting the answers. Where you are going to find 100 developers who don't mind answering this stuff? (Hint: p.se will get you your "first strike".)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm going to use "Name a programming language"!  We are just going to do an informal ranking in my own small team; it doesn't need to be scientific for the game we are playing.

Answer (score 3):

What common control structures exist in most programming languages?

1. `if`
2. `while` loop
3. `for` loop
4. `goto`

Answer (score 1):

Name a common *primitive data type*:

(eg.)

1. integer
2. string
3. boolean
4. pointer/reference

Answer (score 0):

If they have studied a history of programming languages or had an overview of a range of programming languages you could ask something like:

Name a programming language that uses curly braces for statement blocks:
C++
C
Java 
Javascript

Name a programming language that does not use curly braces for statement blocks:
BASIC
Ada
Fortran
COBOL

Comment: I think Python would make a significant addition to your second list.